# Is the foreign_key column required when creating an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

`Book` have `author_id`. 
Is it possible to create a `Book` without specifying `author_id`, or is this attribute required?
error: `Author must be exist`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's required by default since rails 5. Unless you specify it's not

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, optional: true
end
```